# React Native connection with SQLite database

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm new with React Native and i would like to know if I can connect with a local SQLite database file (.db) i followed some guide on Github but it doesn't work for me, is there any other way to do it?? (using Android)

Here is the guide I said: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 0):

```
global.db = SQLite.openDatabase(
  {
    name: "silkyMarket",
    location: "default",
    createFromLocation: "~SQLite.db",
  },
  () => {},
  (error) => {
    console.log("ERROR: " + error);
  }
);
function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

add that to your app's entry file like app.js of index.js then you can access it in other files like this:

```
import React from "react";
import SQLite from "react-native-sqlite-storage";

export default class SQLiteScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    SQLite.DEBUG = true;
  }

  ExecuteQuery = (sql, params = []) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.transaction((trans) => {
        trans.executeSql(
          sql,
          params,
          (trans, results) => {
            resolve(results);
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
      });
    });

  // Create Table
  async CreateTable() {
    let Table = await this.executeQuery(
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(16), last_name VARCHAR(16), is_deleted INTEGER)",
      []
    );
    console.log(Table);
  }
}
```